How do I implement floors and ceilings properly to my DOOM Style Renderer?
I'm working on a tiny DOOM Style Renderer and I've managed to piece together something that can render walls. I pieced it together by looking at videos from 3DSage and The Old School Coder; I got a clipping function from Yuriy Georgiev's Github for his DOOM Style Renderer which fixed my "bending wall" problem. My goal for this project is to get something working well enough that I can eventually make a small game and learn some stuff about software renderers.
Onto my problem, I've tried to use the technique 3DSage used in his Let's Program DOOM series and used that for my thing here. The technique which can be used to render floors and ceilings is where you save a Y-Position for a column when you're creating walls at the 'top', then save the 'bottom' Y-Position which allows you to draw a floor. This doesn't work, because whenever I go inside of a sector or area (whatever you'd like to call it), the walls are always backfacing and the 'x' index for floorx_ylutT is never set to Y2.
I'd like to know how I should fix my problem and be pushed in the proper direction. I'm more than happy to provide more details.
Here's a video showcasing the problem.
from numba import njit, prange
from clipping import Clipping
from vector import Vector3
import numpy as np
import pygame, math

screenArray = None
W, H = None, None

emptyx_ylut = [0]*320
floorx_ylutT = [0]*320
floorx_ylutB = [0]*320

def clearfloorCeilLut():
    global floorx_ylutT
    global floorx_ylutB
    floorx_ylutT = emptyx_ylut.copy()
    floorx_ylutB = emptyx_ylut.copy()

@staticmethod
@njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def rasterizeFloor(screenArray, floorx_ylutT, floorx_ylutB):
    def canDraw(x, y):
        if x > W-1 or x < 1 or y > H-1 or y < 1:
            return False
        if (screenArray[x, y][0] + screenArray[x, y][1] + screenArray[x, y][2]) > 0:
            return False
        return True
    for x in prange(1, W-1):
        pfy1 = floorx_ylutT[x]
        pfy2 = floorx_ylutB[x]
        if pfy1 < pfy2 and pfy1 != 0 and pfy2 != 0:
            for y in range(pfy1, pfy2, 1):
                #y = min(max(y, 1), H-1)
                if canDraw(x, y):
                    screenArray[x, y] = (255, 255, 255)
@staticmethod
@njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def rasterizeWall(screenArray, x0, x1, y0, y1, y2, y3, col, floorx_ylutT, floorx_ylutB):
    backfacing = False
    if x0 > x1:
        x1, x0 = x0, x1
        y1, y0, y3, y2 = y0, y1, y2, y3
        backfacing = True
    dyb = y1-y0
    dyt = y3-y2
    dx = max(x1-x0, 1)

    i0 = max(min(int(x0), W-1), 1)
    i1 = max(min(int(x1), W-1), 1)
    def canDraw(x, y):
        if x > W-1 or x < 1 or y > H-1 or y < 1:
            return False
        if (screenArray[x, y][0] + screenArray[x, y][1] + screenArray[x, y][2]) > 0:
            return False
        return True
    for x in prange(i0, i1):
        Y1=dyb*(x-x0+0.5)/dx+y0
        Y2=dyt*(x-x0+0.5)/dx+y2
        if backfacing:
            floorx_ylutB[x] = Y2
        else:
            floorx_ylutT[x] = Y2
        for y in prange(int(Y2), int(Y1)):
            #y = int(max(min(y, H-1), 1))
            if canDraw(x, y):
                screenArray[x, y] = col            
@staticmethod
@njit(fastmath=True)
def transformVector(v, cs, sn):
    x, y = v
    tx = x*cs-y*sn
    ty = y*cs+x*sn
    return (tx, ty)
@staticmethod
@njit(fastmath=True)
def transformToScreen(f, v):
    x, y, z = v
    y = 1+abs(y)
    sx = (x/y)*f+W/2
    sy = (z/y)*f+H/2
    return (sx, sy)
    
class Engine:
    def __init__(self, w, h, FOV, FocalLength, screen):
        global screenArray
        global W
        global H
        self.w=w
        self.h=h
        self.w2=w/2
        self.h=h
        self.h2=h/2
        self.FOV=FOV
        self.FocalLength=FocalLength
        self.sin = [0]*360
        self.cos = [0]*360
        self.blankArray = pygame.surfarray.array3d(pygame.surface.Surface((w,h)))
        screenArray = self.blankArray.copy()
        W=w
        H=h
        self.screen = screen

        for x in range(360):
            self.sin[x] = math.sin(x/180*math.pi)
            self.cos[x] = math.cos(x/180*math.pi)
    def clip_behind_player(self, ax, ay, bx, by):
        px1 = 1
        py1 = 1
        px2 = W
        py2 = 1
        a = (px1 - px2) * (ay - py2) - (py1 - py2) * (ax - px2)
        b = (py1 - py2) * (ax - bx) - (px1 - px2) * (ay - by)
        t = a / (b+1)
        ax -= t * (bx - ax)
        ay -= t * (by - ay)
        return ax, ay
    
    def update(self, level, character):
        cx, cy, cz = character.x, character.y, character.z
        yaw = int(character.yaw)
        cs = self.cos[yaw]
        sn = self.sin[yaw]
        f = character.FocalLength
        clearfloorCeilLut()
        for sector in level:
            sector_height = sector[0]
            sector_elevation = sector[1]
            walls = sector[3]
            for wall in walls:
                x0, y0, x1, y1, wall_h, wall_clr, wall_portal, portal_bottom, portal_top  = wall
                x0 -= cx
                x1 -= cx
                y0 -= cy
                y1 -= cy
                wx0, wy0 = transformVector((x0, y0), cs, sn)
                wx1, wy1 = transformVector((x1, y1), cs, sn)
                if wy0 < 1 and wy1 < 1:
                    continue
                elif wy0 < 1:
                    wx0, wy0 = self.clip_behind_player(wx0, wy0, wx1, wy1)
                elif wy1 < 1:
                    wx1, wy1 = self.clip_behind_player(wx1, wy1, wx0, wy0)
                if wall_portal: # is it a portal?
                    ## top
                    z0 = cz-sector_elevation-sector_height/2-portal_top
                    z1 = z0-sector_height/2+portal_top
                    sx0, sy0 = transformToScreen(f, (wx0, wy0, z0))
                    sx1, sy1 = transformToScreen(f, (wx1, wy1, z0))
                    _, sy2 = transformToScreen(f, (wx0, wy0, z1))
                    _, sy3 = transformToScreen(f, (wx1, wy1, z1))
                    rasterizeWall(screenArray, sx0, sx1, sy0, sy1, sy2, sy3, wall_clr, floorx_ylutT, floorx_ylutB)
                    ## bottom
                    z0 = cz-sector_elevation+portal_bottom
                    z1 = z0-sector_height/2+portal_bottom
                    sx0, sy0 = transformToScreen(f, (wx0, wy0, z0))
                    sx1, sy1 = transformToScreen(f, (wx1, wy1, z0))
                    _, sy2 = transformToScreen(f, (wx0, wy0, z1))
                    _, sy3 = transformToScreen(f, (wx1, wy1, z1))
                    rasterizeWall(screenArray, sx0, sx1, sy0, sy1, sy2, sy3, wall_clr, floorx_ylutT, floorx_ylutB)
                else:
                    z0 = cz-sector_elevation
                    z1 = z0-sector_height
                    sx0, sy0 = transformToScreen(f, (wx0, wy0, z0))
                    sx1, sy1 = transformToScreen(f, (wx1, wy1, z0))
                    _, sy2 = transformToScreen(f, (wx0, wy0, z1))
                    _, sy3 = transformToScreen(f, (wx1, wy1, z1))
                    rasterizeWall(screenArray, sx0, sx1, sy0, sy1, sy2, sy3, wall_clr, floorx_ylutT, floorx_ylutB)
            rasterizeFloor(screenArray, floorx_ylutB, floorx_ylutT)
    def draw(self):
        global screenArray
        pygame.surfarray.blit_array(self.screen, screenArray)
        screenArray = self.blankArray.copy()
```


To mark a question as solved, post your solution in the box below that says "Your Answer". After a short delay, you'll be able to mark that answer as "Accepted" by clicking the ✅ to advertise that it worked for you. Please do not edit solutions into questions — questions and answers should always remain in their separate sections for clarity.

Problem was solved easily, but with a lot of wasted time thinking about how. The solution lies with logic: if the walls within the sector are either backfacing or not if you are outside of it, then you are able to save 2 Y-Coordinates for each column for the floor and ceiling. However, if you are inside of the sector, then these walls are always going to be backfacing meaning you can only save 1 Y-Coordinate. The way to resolve this is by giving the lookup tables a default value.
If you are inside of a closed room (no portals/windows), then the top/bottom lookup table (however you ordered it) should have a default value depending on whether it is a floor or ceiling - for the ceiling in PyGame, this would be 1, for the floor, this would be H-1. This works, because you are substituting what is unable to be saved with a default value. This should be the opposite if you are working with portals/windows (these are just holes in a sector which let you see into other sectors from what I know)
